# The notification sound does not want to shut down by hardware key

Tags: ios, audio, uilocalnotification

"I'm making iOS alarm application.

currently it's proceeded through UILocalNotification.

but when alarming on scheduled time, I want to stop alarming only in the application.
app is backgrounded.
generally when alarming through UILocalNotification, it's possible to kill the alarm sound as hardware key. 
what should I do?

help ~~

Answer (score 0):

There's no published way currently to handle this. You can make this using any private API's like [Sound Switch](http://sharkfood.com/content/Developers/content/Sound%20Switch/). Apple will not accept your app in AppStore.

Comment: 알람몬 and Wake up (UNIQLO) app, and the function of the question.